# Запуск Реакт приложения, консоль сообщает: Local: at: http://localhost:3000. не работает: Your Network: http: //192.168 X.XXXX:YYYY

Tags: reactjs, webpack

React
После запуска npm start
терминал предлагает следить за приложением по основному адресу:

```
Local: http://localhost:3000.
```

И на любых устройствах в этой локальной сети по адресу типа:

```
On Your Network: http: //192.168.1.246:3000
```

Вторая часть может не работать в некоторых локальных сетях.

Как добиться, что бы это работало?

Answer (score 1):

В терминале выполните команду:

```
webpack-dev-server --port 3000 --hot --host 0.0.0.0
```

Если будет предложено проинсталлировать что-нибудь, соглашайтесь.

```
Otherwise
npm install --save-dev webpack-cli
or
yarn add webpack-cli --dev
will install it
```

Если после инсталляции предложит

```
 npm audit fix
```

выполните это тоже.

Теперь все работает.